# Como ler arquivos PDF usando linguagem C?

Tags: c, string, pdf

Tenho que ler um arquivo PDF usando `linguagem C` e buscar uma `string` presente no arquivo. Porém ao puxar o arquivo pela função `fopen` e exibi-lo na tela, aparece todo aqueles caracteres codificados, da mesma forma quando abre-se o PDF usando um editor de texto, por exemplo. 
Como faço para decodificar o arquivo e fazer o `parse` correto para buscar a `string`? Existe alguma biblioteca, e se possível como utilizá-la ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, não se esqueça de fazer o [tour]. O ideal é que adicione na pergunta o código que já tentou fazer. Assim fica mais fácil para a comunidade te ajudar. Links úteis: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Você pode extrair o texto contido no arquivo PDF para então fazer o parse. Olha só esse [código](https://github.com/agiz/pdftotxt).